# Have a workflow send a different email based on yes/no answer combinations

Tags: workflow, email

I need some help with a work flow.

Every morning we complete a daily checklist to make sure are several applications are working, each application has a different point to test. If the point is working then somebody marks it as completed. If it's not, then  its marked so and then the details are filled in an issue box.

I have a workflow that will send out a certain email if everything is working fine, another for each type of application if an issue is found.  What I need help with is, if there are a combination of issues to be sent out in just one email, then how do I achieve that.

As of now, email is being sent out not only for the combination but also for the particular application as well.

Anyone know of how to set up the work flow correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a column for each application? You then have one list-item for all status and it is easier to built an email from one list-item settings

Comment: You still run into the two emails being sent instead of one.  So here's an example: I need to test Word, Excel and Access.  If all work fine that's one email.  If one app fails that's another email for that application.  If a combination of the apps fail that should be it's own email as well.  However the work flow will also send out an email for that particular application as well as the email for the combination.  So while yes each app has it's own column it won't solve the multiple email being send out when a combination of them fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list with 3 columns for each application you have -
   Application, Issue (Yes/No) and Issue details.
2. Create a workflow for added event.
3. Create a Variable: Issues List
4. Create a Variable: NoIssues (Default: Yes)
5. For current item, write a series of if statements to check Issue
   column for each application and mark the variable, NoIssues as
   'False' if there is an issue with any application and capture the
   issue details of the application and append to the variable, Issues
   List.
6. At the end check for variable, 'NoIssues' and send email using the
   variable, 'Issues List' if there are any issues or a generic email
   if everything is good. In this case, you are sending only one email
   for any outcome of the checks.

This approach requires hard coding the application names in the logic and data structure. Meaning, you need to change the list and logic whenever there is a change in the application list. This can be overcome by more open design approach by maintaining a separate list for applications and using REST calls to query lists but this simple approach is worth considering in my opinion.